# How to find the min cost to span the entire graph given the start and end vertices in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have been given the start and the target vertices. Now the problem is that I have to reach the target from the start vertex covering all the other vertices in minimum cost. Is is a mixture of shortest path and minimum spanning tree. How to approach this problem.

Comment: Just to clarify: it is arcs that are weighted, not nodes, right?

Comment: yes the arcs or edges are weighted